# takeLatest task cancelling based on some arguments of action payload

Tags: redux-saga

I've an action (ACTION) with payload format as `{a: …, b: …}` and following is the takeLatest code.

`yield takeLatest(ACTION, task);`

Now, any previous task is cancelled if ACTION is fired again, however is there a way to have this task cancellation based on arguments?

For eg. something like below

`yield takeLatest(ACTION, task, (action1, action2) => (action1.a === action2.a))`

Now, any previous task is cancelled only if the value of 'a' key is same.

A simple scenario:

```
ACTION with payload {a: 1, b: 1} - Task 1 starts running


ACTION with payload {a: 2, b: 1} - Task 2 starts running and Task 1 isn't cancelled as the value of key 'a' doesn't match.


ACTION with payload {a: 1, b: 3} - Now, the Task1 is cancelled (if it's running) as the key 'a' matches with the first one.
```

Also, on a related note, is there a way to perform clean up code if the task is cancelled as part of takeLatest?

Answer (score 2):

The docs show an example of how to implement `takeLatest` using lower-level redux-saga effects, so you can do something similar [1]. It will take a big of managing state of your other running tasks and how general you want your setup to be.

Taking your example at face-value and ignoring memory leak concerns you could accomplish the behavior you describe with something like:

```
const takeLatestByKeyA = (patternOrChannel, saga, ...args) => fork(function*() {
  const tasks = {};
  while (true) {
    const action = yield take(patternOrChannel)
    if (tasks[action.payload.a]) {
      yield cancel(tasks[action.payload.a]) // cancel is no-op if the task has already terminated
    }
    tasks[action.payload.a] = yield fork(saga, ...args.concat(action))
  }
})
```

This assumes that `payload.a` is a valid object key and that you're not concerned with cleaning up the `tasks` object. You can add code to do that if necessary, and augment the helper to be more general if `action.payload.a` if you'll be using this for something more than just comparing `action.payload.a` but I'll leave that to you.

For running code when a task is cancelled you can do so in a finally block as per the docs [2]:

```
function* myGenerator() {
  try {
    // your code
  } finally {
    if (yield cancelled()) {
      // do cleanup
    }
  }
}
```

[1] https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#takelatestpattern-saga-args

[2] https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/TaskCancellation.html